# Prove $\lim _{x\to 2}\frac{x+3}{x^2-8}=-\frac{5}{4}$ by $(\epsilon - \delta)$

Tags: limits, functions

> Prove $\lim _{x\to 2}\frac{x+3}{x^2-8}=-\frac{5}{4}$ by $(\epsilon - \delta)$

$\forall\epsilon>0, \exists\delta>0\ni0<|x-c|<\delta\implies|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

so i got

$\left|\frac{x+3}{x^2-8}+\frac{5}{4}\right|=\left|\frac{\left(x-2\right)\left(5x+14\right)}{4\left(x^2-8\right)}\right|\le \frac{1}{4}\left|x-2\right|\left|5x+14\right|<\epsilon$

I thought about choosing $\delta_1 = 1 $ but I didn't know what to do next

any hint how to continue ?

thanks

Comment: You seem to be implying that $$\left|\frac1{x^2-8}\right|\le1$$which is not true unless some restriction is applied to delta.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $0<|x-2|<\delta$ implies $x\in N_\delta (2)$. For $\delta\leq \frac{1}{5}$ we have

$$|5x+14|\leq 5(2+\delta)+14=24+5\delta\leq 25$$

while

$$|5x+14|\geq 5(2-\delta)=24-5\delta \geq 24$$

Thus, for $0<\delta \leq \frac{1}{5}$ and $x\in N_\delta(2)$

$$24\leq |5x+14|\leq 26$$

However, you missed something when you assumed

$$\left|\frac{1}{x^2-8}\right|\leq 1$$

This is not true in general. However, what is true is that if $x\in  N_{1/5}(2)$ then

$$\left|\frac{1}{x^2-8}\right|=-\frac{1}{x^2-8}\leq -\frac{1}{(9/5)^2-8}=\frac{25}{79}$$

and

$$\left|\frac{1}{x^2-8}\right|=-\frac{1}{x^2-8}\geq -\frac{1}{(7/5)^2-8}=\frac{25}{119}$$

Thus, for $x\in N_{1/5}(2)$ we know

$$\frac{1}{5}<\frac{25}{119} \leq \left|\frac{1}{x^2-8}\right|\leq \frac{25}{79}<1$$

Choose $\delta=\min\left\{\frac{1}{5},\frac{2\epsilon}{13}\right\}$. For $\epsilon\leq \frac{13}{10}$, $\delta=\frac{2\epsilon}{13}$. Then

$$\frac{1}{4}|x-2||5x+14|\leq \frac{26}{4}|x-2|<\frac{13}{2}\cdot \frac{2\epsilon}{13}=\epsilon$$

For $\epsilon> \frac{13}{10}$, $\delta=\frac{1}{5}$ and we have

$$\frac{1}{4}|x-2||5x+14|\leq\frac{13}{2}|x-2|\leq \frac{13}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{5}=\frac{13}{10}<\epsilon$$

and we are done.

Comment: What happens if $x=\sqrt{8}$?